# Issue with Laravel hasMany relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

I’m having an issue with relations in two of my models in a Laravel application. My models are:

```
class Invoice extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'invoices';

    public function line_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('LineItem');
    }

}
```

And:

```
class LineItem extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'line_items';

    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Invoice');
    }

}
```

In my controller, I fetch an `Invoice` row with the following:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find($id);
```

However, if I try and access the `line_items` property to fetch the `LineItem` rows relating to my invoice, I get the following error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Why is this? I’ve set my models up as per Laravel’s documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many

Comment: Where is `foreach` loop ? Do you have proper keys/fields in tables for making relation ?

Comment: Tried both in my controller and view: `foreach ($invoice->line_items as $line_item)` triggers the error.

Comment: Try `dd($invoice->line_items)` it's not an array but a scalar value.

Comment: Make sure the current invoice has a `line_items`, try using a different `ID` or try `dd(Invoice::with('line_items')->get())` and check the result.

Comment: If I use the `with` keyword, it works. How come it does not without If I’ve set them up as per the Laravel docs?

Comment: Show the output of `dd()` using `with`.

Comment: Probably you are retrieving line items like *$invoice->line_items()* instead of *$invoice->line_items* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change

```
public function line_items()
```

for

```
public function lineItems()
```

and it will work , tested in Laravel 4.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your tables relations... (Schema)

Your FK must be lineitem_id... You have modified this? Laravel will configure automatically... Don't change this...

Then, try

```
$invoice->line_items() or $invoice->line_items in 4.1
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Invoices has many LineItems, therefore my `line_items` table has a foreign key called `invoice_id` that links it to its parent invoice row.

Comment: I See. Sorry.

try change name, line_items instance of lineItems()
Maybe collisions.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Check for `line_items` before the `foreach` loop:

```
if(! $invoice->line_items->isEmpty()){
    foreach($invoice->line_items as $line_item){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Also, it won't hurt to explicitly mention the FK, although laravel will automatically try to do it for you provided you use proper names for your table fields.

```
//Invoice Model
return $this->hasMany('LineItem', 'invoice_id');

//LineItem Model
return $this->belongsTo('Invoice', 'invoice_id');
```